# Map exceeds the maximum number of spatial elements (SSRS 2012)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, postal-code, reporting-services-map

Morning all

I've been trolling the internet for hours and keep getting the same sites with the same answers but no resolutions, so I'm posting on here as its the best place.

I have some experience of creating maps in SSRS using UK ersi files but I wanted to do something with UK postcodes instead. I found a ersi file and am using that as my basis. I am just starting off simple to start with. I have a small SQL stored procedure that returns 122 rows with the postcode region and a total, so nothing major.

I create the report in SSRS, add the map control, link the name field from the ersi to the region field of my dataset. In design mode, it looks perfect. I run a preview and get the dreaded map exceeds the maximum number of elements and I only see the Scottish postcode regions.

Looking at the Technet suggested fixes, first off I cant really filter the data, its only 122 rows, I have reduced the resolution to 0.01 and still no good. Also tried zooming in tighter but no good.

So does anyone have any suggestions as this is really beginning to tick me off as it should be really easy? Could it be the ersi file that is the issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There should be a setting in Visual Studio to change the max number of geographic points in preview mode.  Even then though, I've found it can be very slow as more items get thrown in - you may find it slightly less frustrating in the long run to just be deploying to a test instance of SSRS and testing via ReportManager instead of trying to preview with Visual Studio.